# Aceess only pdf file using Dropbox Chooser in ios

Tags: ios, dropbox, filechooser

I downloaded a simple demo for **Dropbox Chooser**& its works fine for me.
but  `How can I set file type for chooser` same as for JS Chooser.

JavaScript is able to set file type for chooser like as follow:
set options param with `extensions: ['.pdf', '.doc', '.docx'],`

**Help me to solve this**

**Thanks**

Comment: Similar Question but in Android: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27813873/aceess-only-pdf-file-using-dropbox-chooser-in-android

Comment: @DearDhruv, Jatin is copied my Question!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chooser on iOS doesn't support file extension filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [sample](https://github.com/danielbierwirth/DropboxBrowser) which give you the capability to list only the types you want by using
 `dropboxBrowser.allowedFileTypes = @[@"pdf"];`

Good Luck