# Aceess only pdf file using Dropbox Chooser in Android

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I downloaded a simple demo for **Dropbox Chooser** & it works fine for me, but how can I set the file type for chooser same as for JS Chooser?

JavaScript is able to set file type for chooser like so:

```
set options param with extensions: ['.pdf', '.doc', '.docx']
```

Comment: @bryanjclark thanks for edit. please give solution

Comment: as much as I'd love to, that's not how this site works :) I was asked to confirm an edit to your question - I don't have an answer for your question.

Comment: I posted this as an answer, but someone deleted it for some reason, so here it is again (as a comment this time): "The Chooser on Android doesn't support file extension filtering."

Answer (score 0):

The Chooser on Android doesn't support file extension filtering.